# Windows 7 showing subfiles when saving files from internet?

Tags: windows-7, windows

Within the last week, whenever I go to save a file from the internet when I save to "Documents" it doesn't show just what is in `My Documents` at the higher level, it shows all the contents of every sub-folder.

I haven't changed any settings- how can I get this back to normal (so that files of sub-folders are not shown when saving)?

I tried with both Chrome and IE so it's not the browser doing it.

The problem seems to only happen with `My Documents`, no other folders like `Downloads` etc.

Comment: So when you open My Docs to save a file there, it shows every file in every sub-folder as if it exists in My Docs itself, i.e. the view is flattened? That's really weird, never heard of or ever seen such a bug. Are you sure in the top right of the Save As dialog where you have a search box, you don't have a * (asterisk) there by mistake?